# App configuration for Apple review process

Tags: ios

I have written some kind of a banking app which requires logging. Unfortunately, I can't let Apple guys during review connect to my production server, but I can give them access to my development server. Is it possible to modify endpoints addresses in my app after successful Apple review? Because to be honest I don't know how to switch my app from development to production server after review. And I don't know also how to handle updates in App Store which also requires Apple reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to ensure that every API request coming from your app to your server includes a version number.

You can then have your web server direct the request to either the production or development servers based on the version number.

Each time you start an update you increment the version number sent by your app and you update your web server to direct that newer version to development and all earlier versions to production.

Once you finish testing, you submit the app to Apple. Don't use automatic release. Use manual release. Once Apple approves the app, you update the web server so the new version number redirects to production and then you release the approved app.

Repeat again as you start working on the next update.

Comment: Nice idea :), but...

"update the web server so the new version number redirects to production"

And what about old users who haven't updated their apps? Personally, I don't know how to implement such a logic on a web server that users using let's say version 1.1 are redirected to newer versions.

I am using Apache Tomcat server.

Comment: Let's say version 1.0 is in the store and in user's hands. You are working on version 1.1. Your web server would be setup to send version 1.1 to development and anything less than that to production. Years from now you are working on version 5.5.1. Your server is setup to redirect 5.5.1 to development and everything less than that to production. So no matter what versions your users may be using, they go to production. Only one version (the current development/App Review version) ever goes to development.

Comment: Another approach would be to setup a demo account returning predefined data.