# Different web servers for Development and Production versions Swift

Tags: ios, configuration, appstore-approval

I am developing an app, which is using a web based database. I would like to separate the server addresses for the development builds and use this development server during the approval process when Apple is checking the App.

Once it is released, it should use the production server.

Could somebody help me where can I find how this can be made?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53599731/app-configuration-for-apple-review-process

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App configuration for Apple review process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53599731/app-configuration-for-apple-review-process)